# Ejecutar script mediante variable del sistema

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Tengo un simple script en `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"
```

Y lo ejecutó en mi consola mediante un simple:

```
user@host: $ sh script.sh
Hello World
```

Dicho esto quisiera ejecutar lo anterior (`sh script.sh`) mediante una variable "del sistema y/o global" que yo pueda configurar (cómo se hace con los módulos `npm`)

```
user@host: $ SCRIPT
Hello World
```

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Con permisos de ejecución. Y si lo quieres ejecutar desde cualquier ubicación, tendrás que colocarlo en una ruta global... `/usr/local/bin/` es un lugar tan bueno como cualquier otro. Realmente no hay un problema que resolver, solo tienes que leer los manuales de bash.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no hay ningún problema que resolver, el OP no ha intentado ninguna solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando el editor de texto que quieras (en mi caso, gedit) ve a la terminal y copia lo siguiente

```
$ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Estando dentro de ese archivo .bashrc copias lo siguiente en la última linea

```
alias SCRIPT='sh /directorio/donde/este/el/script/script.sh'
```

Luego reinicias la terminal, y ya cuando ejecutes `$ SCRIPT` en la terminal debería realizar la acción que le pusiste.

Answer (score 0):

Primero esto

Haces el archivo ejecutable

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Agregas al PATH de S.O

```
PATH=$PATH:/directorio/del/archivo
export PATH
```

luego te vas a otra carpeta y pones

```
script.sh
```

Si los quieres poner sin .sh solo cambiale el nombre al archivo.